# Move with mouse WPF Window within WindowsFormsHost inside

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a mainWindow within a grid and a couple of wpf UserControls inside this grid.
I have as well three methods that control the movement inside the grid through my mouse.
`MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` and it works properly.

When I add a `WindowsFormsHost` inside one of these UserControl, it just DOESN'T work anymore. I can move the window, but the `WindowsFormsHost` stays in the same place.

I'd like to know how to move a window inside a grid using mouse events when I have a `WindowsFormsHost` inside.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Felipe.

PS. These are the methods I use to move my UserControl inside the grid.

```
public void Control_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = true;
    var draggableControl = sender as UserControl;
    clickPosition = e.GetPosition(this);
    draggableControl.CaptureMouse();
}

public void Control_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = false;
    var draggable = sender as UserControl;
    draggable.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}

public void Control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var draggableControl = sender as UserControl;

    if (isDragging && draggableControl != null)
    {
        Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(this.Parent as UIElement);

        var transform = draggableControl.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
        if (transform == null)
        {
            transform = new TranslateTransform();
            draggableControl.RenderTransform = transform;
        }

        transform.X = currentPosition.X - clickPosition.X;
        transform.Y = currentPosition.Y - clickPosition.Y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try to apply translateTransform directly to WindowsFormHost or see what happens if you use WindowsFormHost.InvalidateVisual() after mousemove

Comment: Thank you so much! WindowsFormsHost.InvalidadeVisual() worked like a charm for me! I had tried everything except this lol.